# Sql plus inner join with where clause (multiple conditions)

Tags: sqlplus

I have two tables - playlist and songs.

I want to select songs from a chill playlist that are the same genre as any song from mix playlist.

The expected result is:

```
song_id  list_id  title  author  genre  duration
  112      02                    rock
```

I came to this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM songs, playlist
WHERE ID.playlist = list_id.songs 
AND playlist.name = "chill"
AND songs.genre IN
(SELECT songs.genre FROM songs, playlist
WHERE ID.playlist = list_id.songs AND playlist.name = "mix");
```

But unfortunately for this exam I am not allowed to combine both JOIN and SELECT within SELECT. So I'm stuck here.

Here are the tables.

Playlist:

```
ID  name   admin
01  mix     mark
02  chill   dave
03  new     anne
```

Songs:

```
song_id  list_id  title  author  genre  duration
111         01                    pop
112         02                    rock
113         01                    rock
114         03                    pop
115         02                    indie
```

Comment: Why do you have this requirement?  Your current query seems like a valid way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to completely eliminate the subquery you have.  One option would be to use an `EXISTS` clause in place of the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM songs s
INNER JOIN playlist p
    ON s.list_id = p.ID
WHERE
    p.name = 'chill' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM songs s2 WHERE s.genre = s2.genre AND p.name = 'mix');
```

This doesn't eliminate the "SELECT within SELECT," but it is a good way to write your query.